# jqchart: Show line without dots/points?

Tags: jqchart

In jqchart, how can I hide the dots in a line graph? I only want to display the line, not the dots for each point. Thanks! I can't seem to find it in the docs.

My current axes are set up with these defaults:

```js
  axisDefaults: JqChart.Axis = {
    zoomEnabled: true,
    reversed: false,
    type: JqChart.AxisTypes.linear,
    visible: true,
    labels: { visible: true },
    majorGridLines: { strokeStyle: 'silver' },
    // minorGridLines: { strokeStyle: 'silver' } // set or uncomment for gridlines between ticks
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it, it's a property of the series called `markers.`

```js
config.series = [{
      type: 'line',
      markers: { size: 0 }
    }];
$(this.chartWrapper.nativeElement).jqChart(config);
```